# Why does my allocation get ignored, when setting values to a workitem-field?

Tags: c#, tfs, tfs-workitem

I'm trying to automatically create a new workitem, after I choosed the project and one of its workitem-types. For test purposes, I'm iterating over all projects and all of their workitem-types, to create for every workitem-type a new workitem. I know, that there are required fields, which have to have a value, before trying to save that workitem. That's why I'm trying to set "default"-values for that field, but if I log the ArrayList, which I get from the .Validate()-method, I can see, that there are the same fields as before. It seems like my allocation to the fields gets ignored.
In the following example, I would have still the field "GemeldetVon" inside the invalidFields list, at the end.

Does anyone seeing, what I'm doing wrong?

Here is my snippet:

```
foreach (WorkItemType workItemType in workItemTypes)
{
    WorkItem workitem = new WorkItem(workItemType);
    workitem.Title = "OTRS-TFS-Connector Test-Workitem";
    ArrayList requiredFields = workitem.Validate();
    if (requiredFields != null) {
        foreach(Field f in requiredFields) {
            if (f.Name.Equals("GemeldetVon")) {
                workitem.Fields["GemeldetVon"].Value = "some Value";
            }
            if...
        }
    }
}
ArrayList invalidFields = workitem.Validate();
```

Comment: Is "workitem.Fields["GemeldetVon"].Value = "some Value";" executed in the if loop? What's the field status in Validate()?

Answer (score 0):

IIRC you should call the `WorkItem.Open` or the `WorkItem.PartialOpen` method before setting Fields' values.

Answer (score 0):

It's done now. It was because of invalid values, which I tried to assign. My example field needs an user as value, an not just some string. It's working, if I assign valid values. Thanks :)